# YouTube rejected my membership offer

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I already have 2 membership offers in my channel. One is just for supporting my channel, they get nothing other than badges. Other one is more expensive and only they can watch my special content.
I wrote a book called ''Bozkır ve İki Çocuk'' and I want to publish it with my videos, but I want another membership offer just for reading my book. I don't want it to be expensive as the second one nor cheap as the first one. So I carefully tried to create the membership offer and it got rejected. When it was rejected, it didn't say anything special. There was a just red frame around the perk tab.[image: Add perk Be sure that you can produce the promised content to your fans Steppe and 2 Boys book This membership is for Steppe and 2 Boys book readers You can read the book with video, once a month]

I translated what I wrote in the image description.
And it said ''Perks can't breach community guidelines'' at the top. What is going on? What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Note: I need to say this again, this is my book. Not a 3rd party content. My book doesn't even exists in the market, I just wrote it.

Comment: Questions that require interpreting decisions taken by cloud computing-based services like YouTube are off-topic. Review their related help article: [Channel memberships eligibility, policies, & guidelines](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7636690?hl=en). You might ask on Meta Stack Exchange for a site recommendation. Tip: Take a look at the tour of [video.se].